# Optiflow based Odometry speed sensing

Tags: arduino, speed, mouse

Am planning to build a odometry speed sensor based on optiflow to measure the speed of the conveyor. I am using ADNS-5020-E from a old mouse of mine and managed to get the X and Y coordinates by interfacing it with my arduino, the problem am facing is to convert this x coordinates into speed.

Comment: The device datasheet should give you the spec. The most important one is the size of the pixel since you can use that information for getting the velocity.

Comment: Am completely new to this, any pointer regarding velocity measurement, thank you. @GustavoLitovsky

Answer (score 2):

The Avago Tech [ADNS-5020-E](http://www.avagotech.com/docs/AV02-0365EN) can be configured for either **500 or 1000 Counts per Inch**, thus reporting back to the controlling electronics once every 1/500 or 1/1000 inch of movement.

Thus, determining speed of movement requires adding up the delta values in the report packets received by the Arduino every set period, say every millisecond, and thus arriving at the appropriate number of 500ths or 1000ths  of inch per millisecond.

Comment: You can't just count the packets; you need to add up the movement delta values in the packets.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will get back to u guys as soon as work on my code.